# Android ActionBar returns null on different activity (API19)

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar

In the main activity I have this code

```
actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setTitle("Title");
```

and it works.

Then in another activity which is called by the first activity, I have the same actionbar displayed and when I call getActionBar() to change the title it always returns null, why?

this is the activity which crashes when setTitle is called because actionbar is null

```
public class SearchResultsActivity extends Activity {

protected GridView grid;
protected TextView categoryTitle;
protected int theme;
private AQuery aq;
private String strSearchString;
private ActionBar actionBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_results);

    setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Holo);
    setContentView(Themes.getGridLayout(theme));

    aq = new AQuery(this);

    actionBar=getActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle("new title"); // <- Here it crashes because actionbar is null

    grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
    grid.setOnItemClickListener(gridItemListener);

    init();

    handleIntent(getIntent());
}
```

the menu from actionbar works without problems on all activities

Comment: Are you a) sure that the new activity is NOT a dialog activity and b) that you are using the proper action bar and not a sherlock or support one?

Comment: It is an activity, and the actionbar is the one built in android, not the support v4

Comment: Please post the activity that is returning null.

Comment: what error u got..? api versio..?

Comment: API 19 and this is the error FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp.SearchResultsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem. For my situation is to use setContentView() before calling getActionBar().

Also please pay your attention to your application theme

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" >
    ...
</application>
```

I think only themes with `<item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>`, can be used.

Answer (score 0):

You are extending from Activity. What if you extend from [ActionBarActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html). Try it and tell us if something keeps broken. You have to add the [v7 appcompat library](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat)

Comment: it is exactly the same as the main activity extended from Activity and there it works. I don't want to use the appcompat library, because the app runs only from ICS and up.